# Caffe docs:"Use multiple classification threads to ensure the GPU is always fully utilized". How?

Tags: multithreading, caffe

In the end of the "Classifying ImageNet: using the C++ API" tutorial (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/cpp_classification.html) I found such phrase:

> Use multiple classification threads to ensure the GPU is always fully
>   utilized and not waiting for an I/O blocked CPU thread.

What do they mean by that? 
I understand right, that there is a way to use multiple threads for CPU layers while running on the one GPU?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple threads on one GPU using [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone) and [CUDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).

As example, of the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#programming-model):

The following code adds two matrices A and B of size NxN and stores the result into matrix C:

```
// Kernel definition
__global__ void MatAdd(float A[N][N], float B[N][N],
                       float C[N][N])
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y;
    C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    ...
    // Kernel invocation with one block of N * N * 1 threads
    int numBlocks = 1;
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(N, N);
    MatAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(A, B, C);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However how to control the amount of threads? (I need to increase it. I have not enough GPU utilization because of the CPU bottlenecks)

Comment: I edited the answer with an example of a kernel launch, when you set the number of blocks and the threads you want to use in each block.

Comment: My issue is that I need more CPU threads, not GPU threads. I have only one CPU core loaded 100% and utilized GPU (30%). 
"Use multiple classification threads to ensure the GPU is always fully utilized and not waiting for an I/O blocked CPU thread" . 

If I understand right - your answer shows how to manage GPU threads and it is not the answer on my question. Right?